# Creating custom hardware Sensors in Android

Tags: android, hardware, sensors, custom-component

I'm looking into creating custom sensors in Android and was wondering if anybody has attempted this. I was hoping there might be a way of creating custom sensors other than by using Android Open Accessory Development Kit.

For example, I manufacture a bespoke piece of hardware which has two water level readers built in. Is there any way of of exposing these to the Android OS via the SensorManager? Has anyone attempted this before? Essentially is there a way of adding custom Sensor items to the SensorManager.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it's not possible to modify the set of sensors provided by the sensor manager - it's a system service with a hard coded set of sensor types.

It would probably be best if you provided an [Android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead which provided these sensor readings which would then be available to any app which needed them.

This service would probably wrap the accessory devkit api to actually communicate with your device.

The service base class you would derive from would be this, which includes examples:

Comment: Thanks... I thought that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience on this, but I did some reading on similar topics recently.

I assume you already know about [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/). I can give a link to a project where the author gets information from some external sensors and the control is done from an Android device. I consider that [this project](http://blog.bricogeek.com/noticias/arduino/el-adk-de-google-en-un-arduino-uno/) is similar to what you want to do.